# Combine 2 prompts into one, showing error condition in red/orange

Tags: bash, prompt

As everyone, I have a customized prompt.  Mine turns red for root and is green for a normal user and a few other small things:

In `bash.bashrc`:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '
```

In `.bashrc`:

```
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

resulting in:

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\$
```

for a normal user...

That is about the maximum of my abilities with prompts, but a really high-level admin has shared his/her/its prompt with me:

```
PS1_Error="\[\033[31;1m\]"
PS1_Normal="\[\033[0m\]"
PS1_Inside='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$bad\$ '
PS1="\`
        retcode=\$? ;
        if [ 0 -ne \$retcode ]; then
                bad=\" [\\\\\\\$?=\$retcode]\"
                echo \"$PS1_Error$PS1_Inside$PS1_Normal\"
        else
                bad='';
                echo \"$PS1_Inside\";
        fi;
\`"
unset PS1_Error PS1_Normal PS1_Inside
```

which has the fantastic ability to turn red with an error and [shows the error number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5uOL.png)!

As I'm too dumb to even understand *how that works* (needed variables are unset???), I'm definitely too dumb to incorporate that one into mine (and I would like orange for an error condition...)

As the high-level admin is a really busy guy/girl/neuter, I'm asking on U&L if there is anyone here who understands the above and wants to <strike>teach me how to fish instead of giving me a fish?</strike> help me incorporate the nice `PS1` into the dumb one and explain a bit what's happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These variables describe the prompt itself:

```
PS1_Error="\[\033[31;1m\]"
PS1_Normal="\[\033[0m\]"
PS1_Inside='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$bad\$ '
```

The colors are done using [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). `\033` is the escape character (33 = 27 octal), then `[31;1m` sets text color 31 and effect 1. `[0m` sets effect 0, i.e. all default. Note how `PS1_Inside` is in *single* quotes (`''`), this means variable substitution is not performed at this step. (It will happen later.)

The real magic happens here:

```
PS1="\`
         ...
\`"
```

This sets PS1 to the output of executing the code within the ``` `` ``` characters. *Variable expansion will happen to whatever comes out.* The code will run *every time the prompt is shown*. The code itself runs like so:

```
        retcode=\$? ;
```

`$?` contains the result of the previous command. Zero means OK, anything else is a fail condition. This is stored in `retcode` for the time being. Everything needs to be escaped, because we want variables to be accessed when the code runs, not substituted at the time of definition.

```
        if [ 0 -ne \$retcode ]; then
```

If it is not zero, something went wrong. So we echo the prompt style used for errors. `bad` is used in `PS1_Inside` above. `PS1_Error` is used to change the color, `PS1_Normal` is used to change the color back to normal.

```
                bad=\" [\\\\\\\$?=\$retcode]\"
                echo \"$PS1_Error$PS1_Inside$PS1_Normal\"
        else
```

In this case, no error occurred, so we don't do any colors and just output `PS1_Inside`. `bad` is set to empty, so nothing will show up in the prompt.

```
                bad='';
                echo \"$PS1_Inside\";
        fi;
```

Finally, the helper variables are unset so as not to clutter up the environment.

```
unset PS1_Error PS1_Normal PS1_Inside
```